# Extjs setValue of combobox doesn't show displayField

Tags: extjs, combobox, setvalue

I'm setting the value of a combobox using `combo.setValue(value)` passing an id that is linked to a displayField. The problem is that I want to show the displayField not the id, it seems like extjs does not make the conversion.

```
{
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Categoria',
                    name: 'categoria',
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    blankText: 'Campo obbligatorio',
                    typeAhead: true,
                    displayField: 'categoria',
                    valueField: 'id',
                    store: comboCategoriaStore,
                    columnWidth: .2,
                    margin: 5,
                    listeners: {
                        select: {
                            fn: me.onFieldBlur,
                            scope: me
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Ensure the combo store is loaded before calling `setValue`. See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3840441/1387519).

Comment: I forgot to set `autoLoad:true` on the store. Thanks for the fast reply